# Connecting to a mongodb server created by amazon cloudformation

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I set up an amazon mongodb server using [this official quickstart.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/mongodb-on-the-aws-cloud-new-quick-start-reference-deployment/)
It created an NAT instance and a mongodb server instance. How can I connect to the server instance? I tried adding an elastic IP, but this does not work.

Edit: I want to use this database in an application, not just connect to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with the same problem (use the mongo database with e.g. elastic beanstalk), aws puts mongo in a vpc, and there seems to be no way to go through the nat instance and connect to the database the way I wanted to.

Here is what I did:

- Create a vpc with public and private groups, and create a small instance in the public group that you can ssh into (add 22 access). This can be a free instance.
- Launch mongodb using the [quickstart for an existing vpc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/step2b.html).
- SSH into your "gateway" instance and then ssh again into the private mongodb instance.
- add a database and user (taken from [this](https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/mongodb-auth/) page).

Run this in mongodb console:

```
use example_db

db.createUser({
    user: 'user',
    pwd: 'secretPassword',
    roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db:'example_db'}]
})
```

- Make a mongodb url.

Example:

```
mongodb://user:secretPassword@10.0.0.1/example_db
```

- Launch your application that uses the database in the vpc. In my case, I was running nodejs with elastic beanstalk. In elastic beanstalk you **must** click configure more options in the creation and add a vpc there. Keep the load balancer public.
- Use the mongodb url in your app, because they are in the same vpc the private ip should work.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to connect to the MongoDB instance directly. You should first SSH to the NAT instance, and then from the NAT console use the private IP of the mongoDB instance to connect to it.

Comment: I know I can ssh into the instance, but I wanted to use this database with a public application.

Comment: @Robert Then why don't you remove the NAT, and add an elastic IP to the Instance running the mongoDB server

Comment: Tried that, did not work @Shubham I think it was a problem with internet access for the instance

Comment: @Robert try launching it in a vpc with internet gateway or you can try lightsail, which is basically EC2 with a nice package